# How to store login session on android studio with php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, webview, android-edittext

I created an android app, but using webview. I want to ask, can we login using EditText column on android, then data on EditText saved to login php session. After that the profile is displayed on the webview. How do I make it?

Comment: Programming. Start with `<?php ?>` and fill in the rest. The question you must be able to answer when asking here is simple: **What did you try?**

Comment: @tadman I mean, I took the value via edittext on android. Then save it in the login session php. Then display it to webview.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you want. What matters is what you've tried. There's no code here.

Comment: @tadman The first one I want to ask, can it happen? Because I'm a beginner, so I do not understand what keywords I want to create on search engines.

Comment: [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a good place to start. I'd strongly suggest looking at the various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/)
 out there and find one that suits your style and needs. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good example of one that's well documented and beginner friendly, and will serve as a foundation for building out the functionality you're talking about.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being a beginner, I understand where you're coming from, but Stack Overflow has a pretty narrow focus: Answering problems relating to code. Advice-based questions are off-topic and are better steered towards forums, chat rooms, or things like that.

Comment: @tadman I've created a webview-shaped app, and stuck on the login process. And I do not know how logic to access input / edittext on android studio and connect to php.

Comment: @tadman Do you think can i make an app like that? You understand what I mean?

Comment: The login process seems simple and banging together a quick and dirty one isn't hard, but doing it properly, making one that's actually secure, is really complicated and time consuming. This is why I'd strongly recommend you use a framework, any framework, that comes with a login method built-in. Have a look at [Laravel's Authentication System](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) as an example of how these work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this line of code in your webview:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

it is disabled by default for space savings and security.